# MySQl Sum(Count() - Count() function

Tags: mysql

Hi I need to figure out why the last part of my code will not run.

Any help would be great.

```
SELECT
xxxx,
  xxxx,
   xxxxy,

   COUNT(xxxx) * xxxx AS Driver_fees,
   COUNT(xxxx) * xxxx AS Revenue,

-- 'This section will not run' 
   SUM((COUNT((xxxx) * xxxx)) -
   (COUNT((xxxx) * xxxx))) AS Gross_Profit

FROM
   xxxx INNER JOIN xxxx ON xxxx` = xxxx
   WHERE week = 11 AND day ='Sunday'
   GROUP BY week, date
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to show the error message you are getting. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order for us to help answer your question, please provide as much information as possible. Please try to explain what it is you are trying to do, what you are expecting and what is happening instead. Providing any errors are always helpful and redacting information from the question or code snippet is least helpful. Provide us all the info you can and we can definitely help you out! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Gross_Profit = Revenue - Driver_fees`, you don't actually want `SUM` in this query, just

```
COUNT(xxxx) * yyyy AS Driver_fees,
COUNT(wwww) * zzzz AS Revenue,
COUNT(wwww) * zzzz - COUNT(xxxx) * yyyy AS Gross_Profit
```